# Table row sorting based on the sum of the each column in jquery

Tags: jquery

Actually, I have this table and need to sort the 'rows' based on the highest value[i mean, in a row, sum of all the columns.]. The last row is total that should also sum automatically.
If I press the 'Top 5', only top 5 rows[based on the sum of cols] need to be displayed. If I press the 'All', then, table has to come to original state.

Any help?

```
<div id="na_1" style="border: 1px solid gray;width: 450px;padding:10px;">

<form>
<input type="radio" name="all" value="All" onclick="Turnthis();"/>All
<input type="radio" name="top5" value="Top15" onclick="TurnOutthis();"/>Top5
</form>

<table id="bt_01" border="1" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr><td>head1</td><td>head2</td><td>head3</td><td>head4</td><td>head5</td><td>head6</td><td>head7</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Subject1</td><td>501</td><td>501</td><td>501</td><td>550</td><td>560</td><td>570</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject2</td><td>620</td><td>640</td><td>605</td><td>650</td><td>600</td><td>604</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject3</td><td>730</td><td>730</td><td>740</td><td>750</td><td>760</td><td>790</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject4</td><td>700</td><td>701</td><td>700</td><td>702</td><td>700</td><td>703</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject5</td><td>220</td><td>201</td><td>202</td><td>222</td><td>210</td><td>203</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject6</td><td>200</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>203</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject7</td><td>200</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>203</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject8</td><td>200</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>203</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>  
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: have you write any piece of javascript for this, if yes please mention.

Comment: This site isn't about providing complete solutions from scratch, but to help with specific problems once you have tried something yourself.

Comment: Hi, I tried, But, I could not make it up to the mark, thats why, I did not paste here.

Comment: ok, you can try with  html templates for rendering table, and the value you want to use for aggregation can be saved in json. it has two benefits first you can do calculations on json which is easy and second is you can create single function to generate html of table based on result of calculations of json data.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6f8j9aaw/4/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Could you please recheck your code?, it is not sorting from top to low value in range of 5.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6f8j9aaw/5/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $table = $('#bt_01'),
    $trs = $table.find('tbody tr'),
    $tftds = $table.find('tfoot td').slice(1);

  var cols = {};
  //calculate the value for each row and column & cache it for future use
  $trs.each(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).find('td').slice(1).each(function(i) {
      var value = +$(this).text() || 0;
      sum += value;
      cols[i] = (cols[i] || 0) + value;
    });
    $(this).data('total', sum);
  });

  //set the overall total
  $tftds.text(function(i) {
    //cache the overall total
    $(this).data('total', cols[i])
    return cols[i];
  });

  //sort the values based on row total
  $trs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(b).data('total') - $(a).data('total');
  }).appendTo($table.find('tbody'));

  $('input[name="type"][value="all"]').change(function() {
    $trs.slice(5).show();
    $tftds.text(function(i) {
      return $(this).data('total')
    });
  });

  $('input[name="type"][value="top5"]').change(function() {
    $trs.slice(5).hide();
    $tftds.text(function(i) {
      var total = $(this).data('total5');
      //if the total of first 5 are cached then use it else calculate and cache the value for future use
      if (!total) {
        total = 0;
        $trs.slice(0, 5).find('td:nth-child(' + (i + 2) + ')').each(function() {
          total += +$(this).text() || 0;
        });
        $(this).data('total5', total);
      }
      return total;
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="na_1" style="border: 1px solid gray;width: 450px;padding:10px;">

  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="all"/>All
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="top5"/>Top5
  </form>

  <table id="bt_01" border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>head1</td><td>head2</td><td>head3</td><td>head4</td><td>head5</td><td>head6</td><td>head7</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Subject1</td><td>501</td><td>501</td><td>501</td><td>550</td><td>560</td><td>570</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject2</td><td>620</td><td>640</td><td>605</td><td>650</td><td>600</td><td>604</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject3</td><td>730</td><td>730</td><td>740</td><td>750</td><td>760</td><td>790</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject4</td><td>700</td><td>701</td><td>700</td><td>702</td><td>700</td><td>703</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject5</td><td>220</td><td>201</td><td>202</td><td>222</td><td>210</td><td>203</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject6</td><td>200</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>203</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject7</td><td>200</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>203</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Subject8</td><td>200</td><td>201</td><td>200</td><td>202</td><td>200</td><td>203</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr><td>Total</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

</div>
```

Note: The markup is slightly changed to use a `tfoot` to put the `total` row